# Why doesn't CGo recognize my struct declared in a header file?

Tags: c, go, struct, cgo

I am getting the error **"./test.h:10:3: error: unknown type name 'PROCESS'"** when I include my header file test.h that has the struct definition PROCESS as a part of my C Go Lang application. The code compiles in C with no problems so I imagine I'm doing something very simple incorrectly...

```
package main

// #include <sys/mman.h>
// #include <errno.h>
// #include <inttypes.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include "test.h"
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
    _"unsafe"
  )


func main() {
    fmt.Println("Retrieving process list");

}
```

The contents of test.h are below...

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct PROCESS {
    char *name;
    int os_type;
    addr_t address;
    PROCESS *next;

    //fields we care about
    unsigned int uid;
    unsigned int gid;
    unsigned int is_root;
    unsigned int io_r;
    unsigned int io_wr;
    unsigned int io_sys_r;
    unsigned int io_sys_wr;
    unsigned int used_super;
    unsigned int is_k_thread;
    unsigned int cpus;
    unsigned long hw_rss;
    unsigned long vma_size;
    unsigned long map_count;
    unsigned long pages;
    unsigned long total_map;
    unsigned long min_flt;
    unsigned long mm_usrs;
    unsigned long nr_ptes;
    unsigned long nvcsw;

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, (unlike C++), the `struct` keyword does not declare a type-name that can be used on its own; it needs qualification with the `struct` keyword. The type is `struct PROCESS` not `PROCESS`:

```
struct PROCESS 
{
    char* name ;
    int os_type ;
    addr_t address ;
    struct PROCESS* next ;   // The struct keyword is needed here
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly, thank you Clifford. I refactored from C++ to C to avoid having to use SWIG and didn't even know that would be an issue. Thank you.